# Auto Build on specific configurations

Tags: tfs, configurationmanager, multiple-projects

Currently using vs2010.

While trying to expand on this previous question:

[Create multiple versions of a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086591/create-multiple-versions-of-a-project-in-visual-studio-using-build-configuration)

How can you now AUTO build on each configuration?  is that possible?  I need to have TFS trigger these specific builds.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Build Definition -> Process -> 1. Required -> Items to Build -> "Configurations to Build".

Select the configurations in which you want your solution to be compiled.

Comment: sry for delay, just getting back to this.  so when i try this, i don't get all the available configurations from the solution to try from. only ones available are the cookie cutter, Debug / Release.  yet i have many more available from that solution.  when i manually enter in the correct configuration to build it runs indefinitely .. when it should only take at most 5mins... i have to cancel the build manually.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the right configuration names? They are case sensitive. I would say start with Debug then add Release, then keep adding 1 more and see what happens. That will tell which one is causing the build definition to hang.

Comment: so this solution includes the 'upgrade', and the main exe, along with the common supporting dlls for both.   now when i build manually using the specific configuration i created in the solution for each, all is good.. but i can't do it through the Team Explorer Build Definitions.. they just don't show up... none of the configurations show up.  when i create one (add) of the same name, it does do something ... but the folders (destination) only contains log file.. nothing else. the log file only lists a warning, no errors.. but nothing much more.

Comment: 1. When you build a single configuration (not debug,release) but a new one you created. Is it generating the output?
 2. If you have access to the TFS build server, check and make sure that the compilation is successful and the files you want are generated on the server? 
 
I believe that the default build template is not copying the
    binaries to the drop location for the new configurations.

Comment: ALso in the project properties, check what is the output path mentioned for the projects? Make sure that each configuration outputs to a different path. 
If you want to edit build definition to organize the binaries in drop location, check the below link: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977206(v=vs.100).aspx