# Shared source file between .net3.5 and .net4.0 projects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the same file that i want to compile in a .net 3.5 project and a 4.0 project.

The api has changed the between the versions of .net, for example I have the following line of code which shows a splash screen on startup:

```
.net 4.0: splash.Show(false, true);
.net 3.5: splash.Show(true);
```

How can i use the same source file in both projects?

Comment: This is surprising to me. What happens in .NET 4.0 when you call `splash.Show(true)`?

Comment: that can be achieved with conditional compiling
see this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-sharp-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets

Comment: @JohnSaunders: nothing happens, its valid, whats not valid is having splash.Show(false, true); in .NET 3.5

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, we also need the same mechanism elsewhere so conditional compiling is the best solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a a conditional compilation symbol in the properties page of your project that encloses the problematic file, for example

```
NET40
```

then, in code write

```
#if NET40 
    splash.Show(false, true);
#else
    splash.Show(true);
#endif
```

You could also create two different Configuration Settings with the `Configuration Manager`. 
In the first one you don't have the NET40 defined and you could call it `CompileFor35` while in the other one you define the compilation symbol and call it `CompileFor40`.

At this point, to switch from one version to the other one, you could simply recall the appropriate configuration setting from the menu `BUILD->Configuration Manager`

You could read about the steps required in a bit more detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086591/create-multiple-versions-of-a-project-in-visual-studio-using-build-configuration/10086766#10086766)